# Second AsyncTask not executing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask

I have 2 AsyncTask, one which is creating a socket connections and anotherone that is transmitting objects using those sockets. my code is this:

```
try {
        connectat = true;
        transmitter = new SocketTransmitter();
        transmitter.execute();
        connector = new socketConnector();
        connector.execute(owner);

        this.open();
    } catch (IOException e) {
```

However, the `AsyncTask` called `socketConnector` is never created or executed. I tried to change the order but then transmitter is not created or executed...

Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hated it when HONEY COMB changed the multiple AsyncTask execution from concurrent to sequential.
So every time I execute an AsyncTask, I do something like this.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

But the thread pool size is 5, if you add the sixth task, it will be added in a queue, and will not be executed until one of the 5 thread has finished.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know which API level you are using, I would suggest you to go through [ASYNC TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

According to the documentation:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread.   Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing `transmitter` in `connector's` `onPostExecute()` or vice versa ?

Comment: is not possible because both asyncTask have blocking and may be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

I had wrote class for execute AsyncTask concurrently.

Check it out:

### [Android-AsyncTask-Executor](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/Android-AsyncTask-Executor)

It takes all work for running AsyncTask concurrently on any Android OS version, it is better that using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

Because AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR available only on api >= 11

With my class you just need to write:

```
AsyncTaskExecutor.executeConcurrently(task, params);
```

And that is all. **No errors on** Android 2.x, 3.x and 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Like Robin Chander said, it's likely running serially and you can use executeOnExecutor...but it isn't available until Android 3.0. If you want full compatibility, you need to dump `AsyncTask` and use `Runnable`.  If you need to report results on the UI thread, don't forget to use a `Handler`.