# How to re-execute asynctask again?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a page where user enters the handphone number to check if it exists in the database. What I have noticed is that, asynctask will only run successfully the first time and store the result somewhere, so when i enter a valid handphone number which is not in the database the next time, it will still tell me handphone number is not valid!

I know asynctask is run by single thread on default. Any solution to solve this?

This is my code:

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.searchfor:
            hp = handphone.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin().execute(hp);
            break;
        default:
            break;


 class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("hp", args[0]);
            Log.d("request", "starting");
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    FIND_FRIENDS, "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

                return json;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
```

Comment: re you getting the correct result on first time....?

Comment: yes. But the thing is I need to re-run again as I am trying to validate the handphone number on the same page

Comment: Okay, I am working...! One second

Comment: Please check the console, are you receiving any warning, because as you know each Asynctask on one thread by default

Answer (score 0):

May be Its the problem of running on a single Asynctask at a time...!
Please made a possible check,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

Adopted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13657249/4360419) link...!