# asynctask not getting arraylist when called from a handler

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-handler

I'm using a handler to start an asynctask but when doing so, my application crashes. The reason I am stuck is because if I start the asynctask via anything else (eg. onClickListener) then I can run it as many times, over and over again, and it works perfect every single time. As soon as I execute the asynctask from my handler, it immediately crashes the application with a NullPointerException.

My handler looks something like this

```
  public Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      super.handleMessage(msg);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            new sortNearby().execute();
          }

        });
    }
  };
```

Here is part of the stack trace from the application showing the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at badams.android.app.fragments.MainMenu_NearbyFragment$sortNearby.doInBackground(MainMenu_NearbyFragment.java:100)
```

Line 100 of my code is the first line in the asynctask under doInBackground

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < global.places.size(); i++) { //this is line 100
```

I understand that the exception is more than likely coming from "global.places.size()" probably being null, but I am stuck on why its doing that only when called from the handler, as it works fine if I start the task from any other section of my code.

**EDIT**

As requested by @Raghunandan, here is the entire code block from doInBackground in my asynctask, which calculates the distance between a "place" and the user:

```
class sortNearby extends AsyncTask<String, Place, String> {
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < global.places.size(); i++) { //THIS IS LINE 100
    Location locationA = new Location("place");
    locationA.setLatitude(global.places.get(i).getLatitude());
    locationA.setLongitude(global.places.get(i).getLongitude());
    Location locationB = new Location("user");
    locationB.setLatitude(global.applicationLocationManager.getLatitude());
    locationB.setLongitude(global.applicationLocationManager.getLongitude());
    float dist = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
    dist = dist / 1000;
    global.places.get(i).setDistance(dist);
  }
  return null;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

global is a class extending Application and is defined in the Activity like so:

```
global = (ApplicationGlobal) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: @Raghunandan updated the question with the entire code block of the doInBackground.

Comment: asycntask should loaded on the ui thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Check the topic threading rules

Comment: @Raghunandan handler.post() does run on the UI thread, does it not??

Comment: The crucial part is not doInBackground, but rather where does `global.places` come from?

Comment: Raghunandan is right, see this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328645/asynctask-called-from-handler-will-not-execute-doinbackground?rq=1). Why are you trying to run it from a Handler?

Comment: Should load on ui thread public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {.....

Comment: @dmon The handler receives a message from a separate GPS class during onLocationUpdate. What I need to happen is when onLocationUpdate is called, that the asynctask in my activity is executed.

Comment: Why not instantiate the asynctask in onLocationUpdate?

Comment: @dmon I'm updating views in the activity using publishProgress() in the asynctask (sorry that part was not in the code sample in the question), so the asynctask has to run in that activity. Is there a way I can execute the asynctask from a different class?

Comment: So make that Activity implement LocationListener?

Comment: we can't call asynctask from handler @Badams

Comment: @dmon simply implementing it doesn't cause onLocationChanged to be called though. I'm sure it would work if I create a LocationManager and initialize the GPS within the activity, but the reason I'm using a separate class is because I need the GPS throughout several activities / application wide. Hence why I am having so much trouble. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Unless you're sharing a lot of the processing, it might be best to keep the GPS only when you're actually using it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `NullPointerException` is at line 100 then either `global` or `global.places` is returning `null`.

Did you try debugging the same?

Debugging will help you follow what is happening.

Also from the handler I do not see how your `doInBackground` method gets called?

Where is the `global` variable defined? Where and when it gets initialized?

Comment: there is no need to call doInBackground() its a overriden method and it will execute as soon as onPreExecute() executes

Comment: Yes I can see that now. When I answered the class extending AsyncTask was missing. But where/how the global variable is initialized is still missing.

Comment: @BhushanBhangale its up there under Edit 2

Comment: @Badams yes I see that now as you edited after I answered. Anyway can you please confirm the question about the global variables and debugging?

Comment: @BhushanBhangale global is initialized during onResume portion of the activity. As far as debugging, I'm not too familiar with the debugger, I'm sure it could have saved me this question if I had a little more experience with it

Comment: @Badams I afraid without more confirmation if the global variable is getting set or not and does the doInBackground method refer to same global variable its difficult. Debug is very easy in eclipse or in intellij if you are using it, check this for eclipse http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/