# doInBackground Method is Not Working

Tags: android

```
private void registerBackground(){

           Log.v(TAG,"-----regbackgroud method call---");

     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {


          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

              String msg = "";

                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                  }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);

                    msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;


                    setRegistrationId(context, regid);


                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error ::" + ex.getMessage();

                }
                return msg;

            }


          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
              super.onPostExecute(msg);

          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();

          }
      }.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

Here My My code In this
 
1) Preexecuted Method Executed And 
 
2) doInbackground() method does not executed.
please suggest me what should i have to do
and Any Error Occure When JNI Is On ...

Comment: Why do you think it's not executed?  What's in you logcat?

Comment: How u know its not called? Put some Logs in doInBackground method and check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119627/android-sdk-asynctask-doinbackground-not-running-subclass

Answer (score 2):

**No need to call in background**

***Try  Call this method***

```
public void enableGCM() {

        try {
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
            if (regId.equals("")) {
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                Log.v("GCM", "Already registered");
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: whenever i open my sdk manager in that (Deprecated)Google Cloud MEssaging Is shown and cloud messaging is transfer to the google play services Thats why I think GCM is not used

Comment: but this method not used in new gcm