# AsyncTask on Android stops working after 2-5 minutes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Currently building an Android app and checking it on Genymotion running 4.1.1. I'm using `AsyncTask` to call the Bing Translate API to translate from text:

```
class TranslateFacebookText extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
        String translatedText = "";
        try {
            translatedText = Translate.execute(message[0], Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.ENGLISH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ....
        }
        return translatedText;  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String translatedText) {
        message = translatedText;
        confirmTTSData();
    }
}

public void onClick(View src) {
    TranslateFacebookText translateTask = new TranslateFacebookText();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        translateTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, message);
    }
    else {
        translateTask.execute(message);
    }
}
```

I'm using this method to start the task after reading this question: [Android SDK AsyncTask doInBackground not running (subclass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119627/android-sdk-asynctask-doinbackground-not-running-subclass)

I'm doing so, since after about 2-5 minutes from the programs start, the `AsyncTask` refuses to run. That is, `doInBackground` does not get called, nor does `onPostExecute`. the `onClick` DOES get called, creates the new AsyncTask and runs the execution code, but the `doInBackground` does not get called.

This is completely random. I'm not doing anything else - just waiting there for a couple of minutes, and afterwards clicking the button again to see this happen. This is also true with a service which runs every specified time using a `Handler` and `postDelayed`. Here's an example:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Handler periodicEventHandler;
    private final int PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT = 600000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        periodicEventHandler = new Handler();
        periodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask, PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    private Runnable doPeriodicTask = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            TranslateFacebookText translateTask = new TranslateFacebookText();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                translateTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, message);
            }
            else {
                translateTask.execute(message);
            }
            periodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask, PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT);
        }
    };

    class TranslateFacebookText extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... message) {
            String translatedText = "";
            try {
                translatedText = Translate.execute(message[0], Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.ENGLISH);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ....
            }
            return translatedText;  
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String translatedText) {
            message = translatedText;
            confirmTTSData();
        }
    }
}
```

The `doPeriodicTask` runs fine, again creating the AsyncTask and calling the execution code, but `doInBackground` never gets called. If I change `PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT` to 8000, for example, `doInBackground` would get called fine.

Ideas?

Comment: Is your `onClick()` inside your `AsyncTask` class and have you debugged to see if the `onClick()` is getting called?

Comment: If your performing a long running task maybe you should put it into a normal thread

Comment: @codeMagic - `onClick()` is not inside the `AsyncTask` class, it's in the `Activity` which contains the `AsyncTask` class. And yes, it's being called

Comment: @Jamesandresakis - what would qualify as  long running task? and what are the advantages of a thread in this case compared to and `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Don't forget you can use Log.d(TAG, message) to help you debug code by outputting to logcat when ever your program reaches a certain point. Also how is onClick attached to the button?

Comment: @MungoRae - it's a simple `setOnClickListener`. I may have not emphasised this enough - the `onclick()` gets called, creates a new `translateTask` and runs the execution code, but `doInBackground` does not get called.

Comment: A long running task is anything that you may need to run constantly. An asynctask automatically runs and then stops and is thrown into a threadpool automatically and the system handles it. if your task gets ran multiple times it could be getting thrown on a thread in the pool thats waiting for others to finish.