# Schedule multiple async task in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, priority-queue

I want to schedule or queue to execute Multiple AsyncTask in background. I have a AsyncTask for HTTP post request that is running in Service, At the same time i make a one more HTTP request in UI thread of AsyncTask.

UI thread taking too long time to execute, because already one thread is running in service.
How to resolve this problem.?

I need to Pause a service thread and I want to execute UI thread first and then restart a service thread again for AsyncTask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AsyncTasks can share a single thread I would try decoupling them by calling:

`my_task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);`

in place of `my_task.execute((Void[])null)`

as described in this answer: [Android SDK AsyncTask doInBackground not running (subclass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119627/android-sdk-asynctask-doinbackground-not-running-subclass)

Another way would be to use Executor framework and [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).