# Creation of AsyncTask taking too much time Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am making a network call in an  AsyncTask, but the problem i am facing is the amount of time it is taking to start the doInBackground method.

Here is a part of my code:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Temp:",System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
                new Move().execute();
                /*some other logic
            }
    }
```

And my AsyncTask is:

```
    private class Move extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... temp) {
        Log.d("start:",System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
        gson.fromJson(Web.Request.get(some_URL),Void.class);
        Log.d("end:",System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
        return null;
    }
}
```

These are the logs i got:

```
           32658-998/com.example.game D/temp:﹕ 1408923006159
           32658-998/com.example.game D/start:﹕ 1408923035163
           32658-998/com.example.game D/end:﹕ 1408923035199
```

So actually it took almost 29 secs to reach the first line in doInBackground method, where as it took just 36 ms to finish the network call. I tried it many times, the time taken is almost in the same order.

Is it possible to start the AsyncTask immediately? Or is there any other way to solve this problem.(other than a running a simple thread?)
Thank you :)

Comment: What do you have in /*some other logic*? Did you try to comment it and test again? Do you have an onPostExecute overridance?

Comment: Ideally my so called "some other logic" should not affect the AsyncTask right? Because they are two different threads now. By the way i am just doing some calculations in that logic part.

Comment: Why do you have your Move instance without () brackets? Wouldn't you instantiate it like this: new Move().execute()?

Comment: In recent androud versions AsyncTasks execute sequentially on a single thread intended for this purpose, so they can block each other - but you can change that behavior.

Comment: @Eenvincible in actual code there are no syntactical mistakes, just forgot to write it here.

Comment: @user2842342 no problem, I figured it wouldn't have ran if that was part of the code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: Do you have other Asynctask's running?

Comment: I have one running, but it has a Sleep for 2 seconds
(Thread.sleep(2000);)

Comment: @user2842342 post it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `AsyncTask` is waiting for other `AsyncTask`s to finish running presumably if you have any other tasks running (check if you do).

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: Thanx a lot :) ...... that's exactly what was happening after changing  it to execute in different threads 29 seconds came to few ms.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful

Answer (score 8):

If you have another AsyncTask executing at the same time your AsyncTask is probably waiting for the previous one to finish. However you can force the AsyncTasks to start in multithreads

```
 Move task = new Move();
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 else
    task.execute();
```

Hope that helps you, for more information you can read this helpful [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119627/android-sdk-asynctask-doinbackground-not-running-subclass)