# Should I use .executeOnExecutor on my APP?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm doing a `REST API` on `Android` in which I have more than one `AsyncTask` (one for `HTTPGet` and one for `HTTPPost`) and I didn't have any problem with them but, when I tried to execute my `AsyncTask` where I use `HTTPDelete`, it doesn't execute `doInBackground()` method.

Searching in SO I found this solution: [Android SDK AsyncTask doInBackground not running (subclass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119627/android-sdk-asynctask-doinbackground-not-running-subclass) but I'm not secure about using `.executeOnExecutor` or not because I search in the official documentation: [executeOnExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)) and it says that it could be problems.

> For example, if these tasks are used to modify any state in common (such as writing a file due to a button click), there are no guarantees on the order of the modifications.

And I'm using my `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` methods to modify my `database` (I know that it's not a `file` but I suppose that it could gives to me the same problem).

According to this, I'm not secure about what can I do for execute this `.doInBackground()` method because I don't want to have problems in the future.

What should I use?

This is my `AsyncTask`:

```
class DeleteCar extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

   protected void onPreExecute(){
   }

   protected Void doInBackground(Integer... id) {

      try{
          String url = "http://IP of my computer/project/cars/" + id[0].intValue();

          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpDelete method= new HttpDelete(url);
          method.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);

          HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

      }catch(Exception ex){
          Log.e("ServicioRest",ex.toString());
      }

      return null;
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(){
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(){
   }
}
```

And I execute it like this:

```
new DeleteCar().execute(idCar);
```

where `idCar` it's `Integer idCar = new Integer(id);` and `id` it's an `int`.

**Note:** It enters at `onPreExecute()` method, but not in the `doInBackground() method`.

Comment: Is idCar on your execute method an integer object?

Comment: @MdOmarFaroqueAnik Yes, it is. It's an `int idCar = 5;`

Comment: int is primitive. Integer is an object. please try to use new Integer(5) like this way if it works.

Comment: @MdOmarFaroqueAnik Oh, sorry. I though you were refearing to `id` inside the `doInBackground()` method. `idCar` it's `Integer idCar = new Integer(id)` where `id` it's an `int`.

Comment: Use retrofit my friend. It is really faster. I gave you the link below. Thanks

Comment: @MdOmarFaroqueAnik Yes, I saw it and I'm very grateful with you but I need to use in this project `HttpDelete` mandatorily. Any other help with this method will be really appreciated.

Comment: u can not sure your url.. so i can not make it run.. otherwise i can write the code for you.. if you can share your url: omarf.android@gmail.com. Sorry I should ask you for that but i am trying to help you.

Comment: You are returning null from doInBackgroundMethod which is coming to your onPostExecute method. I don't know what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Check my update answer.

Comment: @MdOmarFaroqueAnik I'm returning null to onPostExecute because I don't need to do nothing there (all I need it's doing at doInBackground() method). And I can't put the url because I'm in a local server, it's not a public server so anyway you could access to it. I'm using Slim framework and I have a delete method created there (please let me know if you need it and I can provide it to you). I saw your answer and I put a log like you in onPreExecute and in doInBackground methods, it's why I know that it enters into the onPreExecute method but not on doInBackground(). I expect it clarify a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a dummy code for you:

```
public class DeleteCar extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

    //logging to show that it is working
    Log.d("result:", String.valueOf(params[0].intValue()));


    return null;
}
```

}

I have created different class for my AsyncTask. and then i called it from my activity like this:

```
new DeleteCar().execute(new Integer(10));
```

It is perfectly working/executing the doInBackground method.

My suggestion will be to use retrofit. Here is couple link to learn retrofit: 
1. http://square.github.io/retrofit/
2. Here is one comparison : https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/android-asynctask-and-its-dark-side/comparison-among-asynctaskvolley-and-retrofit/
3. here is a basic tutorial: https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/android-asynctask-and-its-dark-side/retrofit-networking-in-android-tutorial-replacement-of-asynctask-and-volley/

I have been using Retrofit. I am getting really faster response. If you need more help to use retrofit, please let me know. Thanks