# AsyncTask fails when calling it more than once (happens only on older version of android)

Tags: java, android, json, http, android-asynctask

So I'm trying to download 3 sheets from google docs.
I use https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=(link...) to get the txt file.
To download each file I use an AsynchTask class.

The app manages to download only the first file. After that, it just fails with a  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily message.

This ONLY happens when I use my OLD phone which has API 16 (4.1.2). It does not happen on newer ones or my emulator.

Here is my AsynchTask class code

```
public class DownloadSheet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private AsyncResult callback;

    public DownloadSheet(AsyncResult callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        }catch (IOException e){
            return "Unable to download sheet.";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //removes the unnecessary parts from the response and construct a JSON
        int start = result.indexOf("{", result.indexOf("{") + 1);
        int end = result.lastIndexOf("}");
        Log.d("Ints: ",start +" "+ end);
        Log.d("Result",result);
        String jsonResponse = result.substring(start, end);
        try {
            JSONObject table = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            callback.onResult(table);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            String contentAsString = convertStreamToString(is);
            return contentAsString;
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }



    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is){
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try{
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{
                is.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity where I call the class (I call this method on onCreate)

```
private void downloadSheet(){

    new DownloadSheet(new AsyncResult() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(JSONObject object) {
            mLeagues.add(processJsonLeague("England Championship",object));
        }
    }).execute("https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1a5bkkyEtY0xs-BmCLDrhntSneion_h5miqEDfsve-C4");

    new DownloadSheet(new AsyncResult() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(JSONObject object) {
            mLeagues.add(processJsonLeague("Premier League",object));
        }
    }).execute("https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1X5oGmyH4qbPQcGroR2RhwMX_RkoVYcmev4fLu9Rs9Ig");


    new DownloadSheet(new AsyncResult() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(JSONObject object) {
            mLeagues.add(processJsonLeague("England League 1",object));
        }
    }).execute("https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=1hRiDvdLPkQEdTSVxmWEoWXjmCFQodNjMNYi3Fd7yYn0");

    Log.d("Length",mLeagues.size() + "");
}
```

processJsonLeague method code

```
private League processJsonLeague(String leagueName,JSONObject object) {
    ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");


        for (int r = 0; r < rows.length(); ++r) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(r);
            JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");

            String name = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
            double hGoalAv = columns.getJSONObject(1).getDouble("v") / 4;
            double aGoalAv = columns.getJSONObject(2).getDouble("v") / 4;
            teams.add(new Team(name, hGoalAv, aGoalAv));
            Log.d("Team", name + " " + hGoalAv + " " + aGoalAv);
        }



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new League(leagueName, teams);
}
```

So that's it. What confuses me is that this problem occurs on my old device only.

Here is the result of my downloadUrl() method

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
          Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
          Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
          Pragma: no-cache
          Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
          Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 07:06:18 GMT
          Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X5oGmyH4qbPQcGroR2RhwMX_RkoVYcmev4fLu9Rs9Ig/gviz/tq
          P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
          P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
          Content-Encoding: gzip
          X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
          X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
          Server: GSE
          Set-Cookie: NID=88=VmfjKSOqoHkZboIam76WYvlMIpaiTwKSh5sdHZiAstu8fcYs2OXQZOkRQXckYS1ZHiaU-hOlIKUm2bAxfv82dz7ACi6jN0wIJzJm6g5ZAuBTwjunKGwoESg-SufmHiwF;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 14-Apr-2017 07:06:18 GMT;HttpOnly
          Set-Cookie: NID=88=mMkSgEkEYA61zJPS_i2hSHO2oGL8sXgg-mcCwXW1mEbyMx912i1iEWfAXoXqNNYbyN0T_AgKNaPklEWYhqkENhMBFVUacp9yEBdu8HZc6uqbTRjI5RreSUIa39_23kg1;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 14-Apr-2017 07:06:18 GMT;HttpOnly
          Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32"
          Transfer-Encoding: chunked

          00000001

          00000001
          �
          00000001

          00000001
          ��
          00000001
          ��
          00000001
          ��
          00000001
          ��
          00000001
          ��
          00000001
          ��
          00000001
          ��
          00000001
          m
          00000001
          �
          000001
          �
          db
          N�0D��
          �ܳ�*�"7RڦI�D�B�   �d�+j��nP�z\Ñ��vv4�[V��L"Vd���e�TzT�6�9��~�����:��e�W�nD����� z�����HH$��.
          ?��%*�XJ
          ��VT:7�G������p¸�
          �h��Dtz�5:W�bq~{z�r��˯�y����)���e��r?�0��i"� �4�=�
          %��O���,��%����
          0
```

Comment: `AsyncTask fails when calling it more than once`. No that is a bad description. Instead you are starting three tasks at the same time. Asynctasks are handled different on your old one. On your old one they realy run at the same time. While on the newer androids they are executed sequentially.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I'm calling the 3 of them concurrently. I'll try tomorrow to call them after the other has finished to see if that's the problem. If anyone has any suggestions feel free to write it here so I give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question it might help [Android SDK AsyncTask doInBackground not running (subclass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119627/android-sdk-asynctask-doinbackground-not-running-subclass)

TL;DR the default behavior of `AsyncTask` has changed over various versions of Android flipping between serial and parallel execution. Try using `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` for parallel execution or use a conditional block based on the build version to choose as explained in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Will look at it tomorrow and tell you how it went :P

Comment: Saw the post and changed my execute to executeOnExecutor but no difference. The problem doesn't seem to be on concurent threads running as I tested running the second download on my demand after I was sure that the first one was over. It looks like I have a problem with downloadUrl() method. That HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily seems to be the whole problem.